# XCode not seeing python modules

Tags: python, xcode, pythonpath

Let me start by saying that I'm fairly new to Xcode, OS X, and installing python modules.

When I attempt to build my project, XCode tells me that it cannot find a python module:

```
  File "/Users/some_user/some_folder/create.py", line 2, in <module> 
    from peak.rules import abstract, when
ImportError: No module named peak.rules
Command /bin/bash failed with exit code 1
```

I have installed a python module, which says it installed correctly. I can verify that it exists in my `python2.7/site-packages/` directory. I also did `which python`, which gave me `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` and verified that python is using that path python install for site packages, and it appears to be, they're located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. I've searched my machine and I don't have another install of python that I'm aware of. I've restarted Xcode after installing the module and that did not make a difference. I also set `PYTHONPATH` to the site-packages directory specified by the same path given by `which python`.

My best guess as to the problem is that I've not defined my `PYTHONPATH` correctly. Here's my entire `.bash_profile` file.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

PYTHONPATH="$ {PYTHONPATH} : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: You may want to check which Python is used by the script (the 1st line). It should match `which python` path.

Comment: The script doesn't specify a python version, I assumed XCode knew which python to use based on the PYTHONPATH. Here are the first two lines of the python script, the 2nd line in the script is where it is failing: `from os import path as ospath
from peak.rules import abstract, when`

Comment: Please paste the content of the 1st line of the script.

Comment: `from os import path as`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `PYTHONPATH` does not indicate which `python` executable to run.  Rather, it is a way to augment in which directories a `python` executable looks for modules during import operations.  Apple ships versions of Python with OS X; the path to those interpreters are in `/usr/bin`.  From the paths in your traceback (`/Library/Frameworks`), you appear to have installed a newer Python 2.7, possibly downloaded from python.org.  By default, that python probably has symlinks to it installed in `/usr/local/bin`;  its canonical `bin` directory is in the framework, at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`.  While your shell path, `$PATH`, may have been set up to include that bin directory at the front of the search path so that the newer python is found in a shell, that probably doesn't work for Xcode.  In other words, Xcode is using the system Python, not the newer Python you installed. You'll likely need to change some variables in your Xcode project so that the that path is searched first for that Python (or use an absolute path to the interpreter).  You should remove the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable pointing at the `site-library`.  Each Python will, by default, automatically search its `site-library`.  More information is [here](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).

UPDATE: You may have a more basic issue here.  I have no experience with `PEAK` or `PEAK-rules` but note that there are two separate distributions listed in the Python Package Index.  If you just want to use PEAK rules, it appears that you need to install *just* the [PEAK-rules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK-Rules/) distribution and *not* the [PEAK](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK/) one listed in PyPI.  To use with the system Python, try this:

```
umask 022
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 -m peak     # "uninstall" peak if installed
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 peak-rules  # install peak-rules
```

If you want to use the newer non-system Python, just install and use a copy of `easy_install` (google for `PyPI distribute`) or `pip` for it.

Comment: I'll give this stuff a try, however, I am on OS X 10.8, I believe python 2.7 comes already installed. I may have tried installing it manually at some point though, I tried so many things at this point I can't keep track of them all.

Comment: 10.8 does come with Python 2.7 but, from the label you show (Apr 9, 2012) that is from the python.org 2.7.3 64-bit/32-bit installer.  I know: I built it :=)  You can see the Apple-supplied Python in a shell by typing `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks, I'll give this a try again in the next day or two when I'm back at my machine.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell Xcode which one of the pythons to use, I don't need 2.7.3, I'm fine with the one that came with OS X, I'm just not sure how to point Xcode at one version over another.

Comment: Thanks Ned! Peak-rules was indeed installed in the wrong directory, using `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 peak-rules` took care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, when I migrated from OS X 10.9 to 10.10. After much ado, I found that there are two versions of Python and I have been using the older version. I typed 'which python' in the terminal and copied the folder to the Xcode.

With this the problem miraculously disappeared. Just check, it this works...!